# Azure DevOps Pipeline changing certificate permissions for service fabric application

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-service-fabric, x509certificate

I have an Azure DevOps Pipeline that (via a Powershell script) adds a certificate to the Virtual Machine Scale Set object for an Azure Service Fabric application.

The certificate gets installed correctly but the service fabric application has an error when trying to start up saying "Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper+WindowsCryptographicException: Keyset does not exist".

I did some Googling and found this page: [Service Fabric: Authenticating with Azure KeyVault via cert: "KeySet does not exist"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46964941/service-fabric-authenticating-with-azure-keyvault-via-cert-keyset-does-not-ex)

which allowed me to manually fix the problem by longing on to the service fabric node, and giving the installed certificate Read permissions with the NETWORK SERVICE user account.

Is there a way I give the installed certificate this permission via the DevOps Pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following to your powershell script

```
function Set-CertificateReadPermission
{
 param
 (
    [Parameter(Position=1, Mandatory=$true)]
    $cert ,

    [Parameter(Position=2, Mandatory=$true)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string]$serviceAccount
 )


 # Specify the user, the permissions and the permission type
 $permission = "$($serviceAccount)","Read","Allow"
 $accessRule = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule -ArgumentList $permission;

 # Location of the machine related keys
 $keyPath = "$($env:ProgramData)\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\";
 $keyName = $cert.PrivateKey.CspKeyContainerInfo.UniqueKeyContainerName;
 $keyFullPath = $keyPath + $keyName;

 try
 {
    # Get the current acl of the private key
    $acl = (Get-Acl $keyFullPath)

    # Add the new ace to the acl of the private key
    $acl.AddAccessRule($accessRule);

    # Write back the new acl
    Set-Acl -Path $keyFullPath -AclObject $acl;
 }
 catch
 {
    throw $_;
 }
}

# Get the certificate, or use a previous variable:
$cert = Get-ChildItem -Path cert:\LocalMachine\My\EEDEF61D4FF6EDBAAD538BB08CCAADDC3EE28FF

#Call method to set permission on certificate
Set-CertificateReadPermission $cert "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"
```

Comment: This script seems to change the permissions for the local machine that is running the powershell script but the powershell script is something that will be executed by Azure DevOps Pipeline and it needs to affect the Virtual Machine Scale Set for the Azure Service Fabric service.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: There are multiple ways to execute the powershell on the scale set. The microsoft recommend way is a [Custom Script Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/tutorial-install-apps-powershell#what-is-the-azure-custom-script-extension).  You can also use a [script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43502308/639829) in you service fabric application startup.